# Spring authorization server OAuth2 login from my own login page

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-authorization-server

I have a front end (angular) with login form, a back-end for that angular application as my OAuth client (spring dependency) then I have a third application that is the Authorization server and finally the forth is the ressources server.

So I want to know is there is any way to jump the redirect to /login from the authorization server?

I want to login the user with angular login page, then make a get with my OAuth client (spring) for the authorization code flow and then, since i'm not authenticated, instead of getting redirect, I want to get an error "401" and then send a post request with my OAuth client (spring) to the auth server again to login the user that have sent the data previously in angular login page.

Essentially I just wanted to login to my auth server with a custom page that exists in the front end application and let the backend build specially for that front, take over the flow.

Answer (score -1):

You want seamless integration between login form and the rest of your Angular app? Share your CSS between Angular (public) client and authorization-server embedded (private) one, don't implement login in public client.

You might need to better grasp OAuth2 concepts.

Login, logout and user-registration are **authorization-server** business. Leave it there. Reasons are related to security and just being future-proof: what if you want to plug additional clients to your system (mobile apps for instance)? Are you going to implement login, logout and user-registration again and again? What if you have to introduce multi-factor authentication at some point? Would you break all clients at once?

Your "backend" (Spring REST API secured with OAuth2) is a **resource-server**, not a **client**. Make sure [it is configured as so](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials): depends on `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` (directly or transitively). This is where the HTTP status for missing (or invalid) authorization is handled. The way to do it depends on your resource-server being a servlet or reactive app. The libs in the [repo linked just before](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons) do what you want by default (401 instead of 302).

In your case, **client** is Angular app. I hope you use an OAuth2 client lib such as [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client) to handle:

- authorization-code flow (redirects to authorization-server, back from authorization-server with authorization-code and tokens retrieval with this authorization-code)
- refresh-token flow (automatic access-token refreshing just before it expires)
- requests authorization (add Bearer Authorization header with access-token on configured routes)

What my Angular apps do for login is just redirect users to authorization-server "authorization" end-point and then just wait for a redirect back to "post-login URL" with an authorization-code. How this code was obtained is none of their business (can be a login form, a "remember-me" cookie, some biometry, etc.).

Also, I have to admit that I don't use Spring's authorization-server. I prefer mature / feature-full solutions like Keycloak, Auth0, Okta, etc. which come with much more already implemented: multi-factor authentication, integration with  LDAP, identity federation for "social" providers (Google, Facebook, Github, etc.), administration UI, ...

Comment: Thx for the reply, totally understand your point, and I'll do as so, but I want to stick with the angular front and Java API being an Oauth2 Client and communicating with the auth server, I don't want my angular app being the one communicating directly with it, I arrived to the point where I can't get the Auth Server redirecting to the login page, I mean, the redirect appears on the browser but nothing happens.

Comment: Hope for you you'll remember there was a link to an Angular lib in this answer (with excellent doc), when you'll get tired to have things not working correctly.

Answer (score -1):

As ch4mp said, it's best to leave all the authentication and authorization logic and pages to the Spring Authorization Server, it's pretty easy to customize and configure all the user accessible pages (login, authorize, etc...) with Thymeleaf, you only have to bring in your CSS to unify the design.

There was a great [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5tlU_Vjv8Ns) in last year's Spring One which seems like something you'd like to achieve, you can find the code in this [repo](https://github.com/sjohnr/springone-2021).
They used [Spring Cloud Gateway](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gateway) as a means to run the Angular SPA in the `flights-web` app, configuring it as the OAuth client. Following this path you can route all calls to your backend API through the gateway's `WebClient`.